# Unexpected EOF while parsing using Python tool cif2cell

Tags: python, eof, traceback

I have an error when trying to use a Python tool cif2cell. What cif2cell does it take a .cif file in and return a .cell file.

Intro can be found elsewhere about what it is, but its basically a materials modelling tool, and what I'm trying to do is input a `.cif` file that represents this 'tile' of atoms, and return a `.cell` file that is a structure of many of these tiles - The supercell.

In my case I'm going for a 5x5x1 supercell, as can be seen.

**Here's the terminal command;**

```
$ ./cif2cell -p castep -f 9000046.cif -o structure1.cell --supercell = [5 5 1]
```

**Which is yielding the following error;**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cif2cell", line 354, in <module>
    supercellmap = safe_matheval(options.supercellmap)
  File "/Users/ 'my name' /Desktop/castep-8.0-macosx-intel/utils.py", line 525, in safe_matheval
    return eval(sexpr,{"__builtins__":None},safe_dict)
  File "<string>", line 1
    =
    ^

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I have seen that the error has been come across by many writing simple programs, but I have not found any resolutions/examples where a tool has been queried.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO since it isn't actually about a programming problem. But it looks like there's an error in the structure of your .cif file. I know nothing about .cif, but that message implies that an open quote / bracket / tag doesn't have a corresponding closing quote / bracket / tag. I _guess_ it's possible that you've stumbled onto a bug in cif2cell itself, although that's pretty unlikely with such a well-used program. But if you have found a bug you need to take that up with the maintainers of cif2cell, we can't diagnose &/or repair such things here.

Comment: Thanks a lot and apologies for being slightly off-topic.